# speech recognition not working in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a simple speech recognition system for a project purpose. I am following a youtube video where the following code was working in that system but when I tried It is showing me error
This is the code

```
import speech_recognition as sr
with sr.AudioFile('/content/male.wav') as source:
  audio = r.record(source)
```

And this is the error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-428b394f05e3> in <module>()
      1 import speech_recognition as sr
      2 with sr.AudioFile('/content/male.wav') as source:
----> 3   audio = r.record(source)

NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

This is the full code

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
import speech_recognition as sr
catch = sr.Recognizer()
songss = sr.AudioFile('/content/male.wav')
print(type(songss))
import speech_recognition as sr
with sr.AudioFile('/content/male.wav') as source:
  audio = r.record(source)
```

Comment: there is no `r` defined in code....

Comment: From where did you get the code? Shouldn't it be `sr.record(source)` (just a guess).

Comment: I am following a youtube video

Answer (score 0):

The `r` is not defined. It should be defined as:

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
```

Hope this will work.